# Is tum’ah transmitted from an animal bone?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

The following passuk in [Vayikra 11:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.11.24?lang=he&with=Mishnah&lang2=he) stipulates

וּלְאֵ֖לֶּה תִּטַּמָּ֑אוּ כָּל־הַנֹּגֵ֥עַ בְּנִבְלָתָ֖ם יִטְמָ֥א עַד־הָעָֽרֶב׃‏
And the following shall make you unclean—whoever touches their carcasses shall be unclean until evening.

Does this apply to the bones of an animal? If so, what gradation of tum’ah is transmitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Mishna Chulin 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Chullin.9.5?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) which says that a bone of a carcass is not *Tameh* and does not transmit any impurity.

However, if it's perforated and one could touch the marrow in it, the law changes and - as the verse says - one would be impure until dipping in a Mikveh and waiting for sunset.

In the original:

> קוּלִית הַמֵּת וְקוּלִית הַמֻּקְדָּשִׁים, הַנּוֹגֵעַ בָּהֶן, בֵּין סְתוּמִים בֵּין נְקוּבִים, טָמֵא. קוּלִית נְבֵלָה וְקוּלִית הַשֶּׁרֶץ, הַנּוֹגֵעַ בָּהֶן סְתוּמִים, טְהוֹרִים. נְקוּבִים כָּל שֶׁהוּא, מִטַּמֵּא בְמַגָּע. מִנַּיִן שֶׁאַף בְּמַשָּׂא, תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר (ויקרא יא), הַנֹּגֵעַ וְהַנֹּשֵׂא, אֶת שֶׁבָּא לִכְלָל מַגָּע, בָּא לִכְלָל מַשָּׂא, לֹא בָא לִכְלָל מַגָּע, לֹא בָא לִכְלָל מַשָּׂא:‏

And the Bartenura who explains:

**קולית נבלה**. נבילה אין עצמותיה מטמאין, דכתיב בנבלתה, ולא בעצמות. וכן שרץ. הלכך סתומים טהורים אף מלטמא במשא, וכל שכן במגע דאי אפשר לו ליגע במוח שבפנים. ואף על גב דשומר מכניס ומוציא טומאה, הני מילי בדבר שאפשר ליגע בטומאה עצמה ואפילו לא נגע בה אלא בשומר, טמא, אבל היכא דאי אפשר ליגע בטומאה עצמה אין שומר מטמא:‏